# Query to fetch from 6am present day to next day 6am

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement to fetch data from 6 am of current day 6 am of next day daily basis. I have to consider 6 am to 6 am as single day. I am able to fetch data from 6 am to 11:59 PM of a day if I want remaining 6 hours which comes next day should also be considered in previous day. Tried many possible ways to fetch the data, but nothing gave me solution.

```
SGHH.DateTime >= DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),120))
 AND SGHH.DateTime <= DATEADD(HOUR,6,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE()+1,120))
```

tried this method but after 11:59 PM getdate() will bring the current data and getdate()+1 will fall to next day.

CAN ANY ONE PLEASE SHARE A SAMPLE QUERY TO FETCH DATA BETWEEN 6am-6am??

Comment: If you want to fetch the current 6-6 cycle, you could add a case statement to your where statement. e.g. case when datepart(hour, getdate()) < 6 then...

Answer (score 0):

You need to Add 6 hours to Today's midnight time, you can achieve that by taking the date part only out of `GETDATE()`:

```
DECLARE @TODAY DATETIME2 = DATEADD(HOUR, 6, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()));

SGHH.DateTime >= @TODAY 
AND
SGHH.DateTime <= DATEADD(DAY, 1, @TODAY)
```

Comment: the problem there is that when you reach the actual midnight boundary, you still have 6 hours before the next notional day begins, however you have suddenly wound your notional day forward by 24 hours - unless that's what he wants of course

Comment: @AndrewDeighton That would be a simple if statement based on the business rules.

Answer (score 0):

what you need is that the time 6 hours ago, was in the actual day that you are now using as a day, so anything before 6am with 6 whole hours deducted will fall in the previous day.

```
CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(),120) <= dateadd(hour,-6,SGHH.DateTime) 
    AND dateadd(hour,-6,SGHH.DateTime) <  CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), dateadd(day,1,GETDATE()) ,120)
```